# using jQuery Validation 'remote' with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm attempting to use jQuery's remote validation method for a basic (well, should be) ajax call to some server-side logic. Now, where my situation gets peculiar is that i'm using SlimFramework and so I'm posting to a route, not a direct script page.

Here is the JS:

```
 rules: {
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true,
     remote: {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/email/check',
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
         email: function() {
            return $('#email').val();
         }
        }
       }
      }
  }
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: 'Please enter an email address.',
      remote: 'This email is already taken.'
    }
  }
```

Here is my server-side logic which I am almost certain is correct:

```
  $app->post('/email/check', function() use ($app) {

    $request = $app->request;
    $email = $request->post('email');
    $response = '';

    $user = $app->user
      ->where('email', $email)
      ->first();

    if($user) {
      $response = false;
    } else {
      $response = true;
    }

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
  });
```

**UPDATE**

To be more specific, when I check the network response in the inspector, its seems the request is being made successfully:

[image]

However, The `remote` validation message that i specified in the `messages` property of the validation object is not being thrown...

**Any suggestions as to why it is not functioning?**

Comment: Try `$response = "false"` and `$response = "true"`.  You also do not need the `data` parameter because the value of the field being validated is already being sent by default.  Otherwise, it looks like it should be working.

Comment: You'll also have to do a better job at describing what "not functioning" means.  Like, have you used the JS console to inspect the ajax call, response, etc?

Comment: The framework would not matter, as long as the URL ultimately leads to the server-side script.

Comment: check updated question for more detail @Sparky

Comment: Again, please explain "not functioning";  and as mentioned in my first comment, you need to enclose the `true` and `false` in quotation marks... you are supposed to be echoing a JSON encoded *string*, not a boolean.

Comment: i have defined 'not functioning' in my question update as the validator not throwing any messages. it allows registration regardless of a unique email or not, and i have enclosed my true/false responses in quotations. still no cigar @Sparky

Comment: Why are you sending headers before the `echo`?  Not sure if that's the problem but I've had no issues using `remote`.